# Can a class be private to a translation unit?

Tags: c++, typedef, private

Consider the following code:

```
/*
 * myclass.h
 */

class myclass_impl
{
    // ...
}

boost::shared_ptr<myclass_impl> myclass;
```

Can I somehow make `myclass_impl` (or, at least, the direct use of it) be private to the translation unit it is defined in, allowing clients to only use the `myclass` typedef? What I am trying to achieve is have the compiler alert me if somebody uses the implementation class directly.

Comment: Short answer: No (client can always use `myclass::value_type`). Long answer: What do you mean by "use"? Certain usage can be prohibited by making certain constructors and destructors unavailable.

Comment: I mean not only instantiation, but any kind of reference to the class (such as using it as a parameter type in a function). I fear in this case it may not possible to make it private :(

Comment: @dandrestor, it's possible make referring to class invalid by making whole type private (putting in some class) :)

Answer (score 3):

Declare your class in the source file (not header file) and it will not be accessible from other translation units.  Then, use forward declaration to declare a pointer/reference in your header file.

Or define a impl header file and comment that it should not be included in other source files.

```
/*
 * myclass.h
 */

class myclass_impl;

class myclass
{
  boost::shared_ptr<myclass_impl> myclass_i;
public:
  myclass() : myclass_i(new myclass_impl) { }
  int getI() const;
};


/*
 * myclass.cpp
 */

class myclass_impl
{
  int i;
public:
  myclass_impl() : i(4) { }
  int getI() const { return i; }  
};

int myclass::getI() const 
{ 
  return myclass_i->getI(); 
}
```

Comment: Could you detail a bit please? By using a forward declaration in the header file, would the class not become available to all other translation units that include the header?

Comment: Yes, it would. But they would only know that there is a class myclass_impl, but not how it looks like (because you are hiding the class myclass_impl declaration inside the myclass.cpp file).

Comment: That means that using a reference or pointer to myclass_impl somewhere in the client code would not result in a compiler error, which is what I am trying to achieve. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, but what would they do with the pointer or reference because you can't dereference it?

Comment: This answers your concern: What I am trying to achieve is have the compiler alert me if somebody uses the implementation class directly.

Comment: @dandrestor, you could go `void *` path, but this is ugly direction, I think. Slight better is going with some totally abstract class that have only virtual destructor.

Answer (score 3):

You can create interface `myclass` and use factory method to provide instances of you private class `myclass_impl` defined in anonymous namespace in same file with method. Other variant is pimpl.

File myclass.h

```
class myclass
{
public:
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
    static boost::shared_ptr<myclass> createInstance();
};
```

File myclass_impl.cpp

```
#include "myclass.h"
namespace {
    class myclass_impl : public myclass
    {
    public:
        virtual void doSomething() { std::cerr << "Hi there" << std::endl; }
    };
}
static boost::shared_ptr<myclass> myclass::createInstance()
{
    return new myclass_impl();
}
```

**Update (added totally awful solution):**

myclass.h

```
class destroyable { virtual ~destroyable() {} };
class myclass {
private:
    boost::shared_ptr<destroyable> pimpl;
public:
    void doSomething();
};
```

myclass_impl.cpp

```
namespace {
    class myclass_impl : public destroyable {
    public:
        void doSomething() { /* ... */ }
    };
}
void myclass::doSomething() { static_pointer_cast<myclass>(pimpl)->doSomething(); }
```

Comment: Well, in my implementation `myclass_impl` has private constructors, and is only created by a separate friend factory class. However, I need the factory class to be publicly available. Could you please detail your answer a bit?

Comment: Can your example be adapted so that I do not need `createInstance()`? I would like to access members of `myclass_impl` through the simpler syntax `myclass_object->method()`.

Comment: There is no difference is it created through factory object or directly through static factory method. Making private constructor will only effect at places where you use `myclass f()` or `void f(myclass x)`, I guess. But you still be able to use `void f(myclass &x)` and `myclass *f()`. Actually I thought that you need to hide implementation details (i.e. to avoid showing `private` section in header-file). Looks like I quiet don't understand the goal you want to achieve. What kind of details you need?

Comment: I want to *not* be able to declare in my client code `void some_func(myclass_impl param)`. I want the compiler to alert me if I do. I only want to be able to do `void some_func(myclass param)`.

Comment: Regarding the implementation details, showing the private parts (:P) in my header file is fine. That's not what I'm worried about.

Comment: You need to expose something that will create object. Or something that will provide existing instance. Otherwise you'll not have any access to myclass_impl. You can `myclass_object = myclass::createInstance(); myclass_object->doSomething();`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, btw. It finally made me *get* what pimpl is all about :)

Comment: But I would still need to do `boost::shared_ptr<myclass> myclass_object = ...`. This means I can also use `myclass` in my client code directly, right? I want to be forced by the compiler to use the `typedef` (or the `shared_ptr<myclass>`) exclusively.

Comment: Agghhh! I got it now! You need pointer to your class, but want to avoid specifying type anywhere in client code. You need class to provide information about what is possible anyway. Using of pimpl class will simulate behavior of `boost::shared_ptr<myclass>` and that will be the only class that can be used in client code (of course you still can use `myclass` as template parameter, but you'll not be able to do anything with it). Some friends of your pimpl-class will be able to setup instance of `myclass_impl`.

Comment: +1 but I think you've glossed over a bit on the effects of using an unnamed namespace -- which seems pretty critical to what OP is trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 1):

(Disclaimer, the use of *public* and *private* in this answer is generic, and not according to the definitions in the standard, but rather meaning *accessible* or *usable* by other translation units. `private` used to signify *public member* as per the standard)

It all depends on the particular definition of the class, and how much needs to be published to other translation units.

If you declare and define the class only in the .cpp file (I would use an unnamed namespace also to avoid name collisions), then the type will not be accessible from outside of that translation unit.

If this class is referenced anywhere where it has to be published outside to this translation unit (there is a member of a public type that is a pointer/reference to class that is public) then the next best thing is providing just a forward declaration in the header (now outside of the unnamed namespace, possibly as a `private` type internal to the class that uses it).

As a last resort, you can provide the whole definition of the type in the header (a public type holds a member of the type directly), but you can still have the type be a private internal type to the public type, disallowing usages outside of that type (and it's friends).

As you see there are differences as to what means private and public, and what can be controlled with it. By not providing the definition in the header and using an unnamed namespace you are making it *inaccessible* to other TU, by only providing forward declarations the type is *known* to exist, but not usable in any context where a type must be complete (a function could still take and forward pointers to the type). On a separate plane, by making it internal and `private` to a different type the definition will be *known* but it will not be usable outside of the `friend`s of the enclosing type...

Comment: Thanks. I guess the closest thing to what I need is a forward declaration in the header file, and the class fully declared and defined in the .cpp file.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what you're trying to achieve. But you have already been asked about that, and failed to clarify it very much. In your answer comment you wrote "I mean not only [to prohibit] instantiation, but any kind of reference to the class (such as using it as a parameter type in a function)".

Taken at face value, this means using the following in your header file:

```
struct BlahImpl;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<BlahImpl> Blah;

// Functions that create or give access to Blah instances.
```

Client code can then create or access `Blah` instances, and copy them (with implied shared semantics), but not actually do anything with them. At best they can then serve as proof that some function has been called earlier (producing an instance). Or perhaps something is controlled by the pattern of calls to functions involving such instances, but anyway, the `boost::shared_ptr` would then be completely irrelevant and superfluous.

So maybe you didn't mean exactly what you wrote, but rather something like "Any `BlahImpl` instance shall be dynamically allocated and encapsulated by a `boost::shared_ptr`".

And if so you can achieve that as follows:

- You can enforce dynamic allocation by making the destructor non-`public`, preferably `protected`, and providing some means of destroying instances (the simplest, to confer `friend`-ship on a common destroy function template).
- You can ensure wrapping by a given smart point in a number of ways. The main problem is to forward constructor arguments. One C++98-compatible way is to do that forwarding via a macro, in which case the "you can not inadvertently create instances other than via this macro" can be implemented by *obfuscation*, namely obfuscation of the `new` expression.

Example:

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stddef.h>         // ptrdiff_t, size_t
#include <string>
using namespace std;

namespace cpp11 {
    using boost::shared_ptr;
};

template< class Type >
void destroy( Type const* p ) { delete p; }

class OnlySharedPtrUsage
{
public:
    virtual ~OnlySharedPtrUsage() {}

    struct InstantiationObfuscation;

    static void* operator new( size_t size, InstantiationObfuscation* )
    {
        return ::operator new( size );
    }

    static void operator delete( void* p, InstantiationObfuscation* )
    {
        ::operator delete( p );
    }

    static void operator delete( void* p )
    {
        ::operator delete( p );
    }
};

#define NEW_SHARED( type, args )                                \
    ::cpp11::shared_ptr<type>(                                  \
        new( (type::InstantiationObfuscation*)0 ) type args,    \
        destroy<type>                                           \
        )

class MyClass
    : public OnlySharedPtrUsage     // The NEW_SHARED macro simplies.
{
template< class Type > friend void destroy( Type const* );
private:
    string  helloText_;

    MyClass( MyClass const& );                      // No such.
    MyClass& operator=( MyClass const& );           // No such.

protected:
    virtual ~MyClass()              // Only dynamic allocation allowed.
    {
        cout << "MyClass::<destroy>()" << endl;
    }

public:
    string helloText() const { return helloText_; }

    MyClass( string const& text )
        : helloText_( text )
    {
        cout << "MyClass::<init>( string )" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    // MyClass     o( "a" );                   // ! Does not compile, not dynamic.
    // MyClass*     p  = new MyClass( "b" );   // ! Does not compile, not "mangled".
    cpp11::shared_ptr< MyClass > sp  = NEW_SHARED( MyClass,( "Hello from MyClass!" ) );

    cout << sp->helloText() << endl;
}
```

Note that this example does not directly support the optimization of `make_shared`. The obfuscated allocator function (formally a placement one) does not fit well with `make_shared`. But I imagine that it can be done by defining an allocator class and using `alloc_shared`.

Also note, this approach supports header only modules; no need for separate compilation. :-)

Oh, and for the general case you would need to also add allocator functions for arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm...

```
class myclass
{
private:
    class myclass_impl
    {
    public:
        void do_something() { std::cerr << "Hello there" << std::endl; }
    };

public:

    typedef boost::shared_ptr<myclass_impl> ptr_type;

    static ptr_type construct()
    { return ptr_type(new myclass_impl()); }
};

int main()
{    
    myclass::myclass_impl *x; // error: 'class myclass::myclass_impl' is private
    myclass::ptr_type::element_type *y; // ok
    myclass::ptr_type x = myclass::construct();
    x->do_something(); /// Hello there
}
```

Is that what you wanted?

P.S. Note that there is no way to hide `myclass_impl`, because `boost::shared_ptr<T>` provides access to underlying type.